# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Annotation Entity wrong "Created by" Field value

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-sdk

I am working with Dynamics CRM annotation, i developed an external application that use the organization service in order to create new annotation linked to a custom entity and linked to the user based on the user id, by set the CallerId in the organization Service and by set the field "CreatedBy" in the annotation object on create.

The problem is that the annotation is sometimes the value of "Created by" is not correct and it randomly set it by another user.

below used code:

```
 Guid callerID = new Guid(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["CallerId"].ToString());


 CrmServiceClient connection = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
 OrganizationServices = connection.OrganizationServiceProxy;
 OrganizationServices.CallerId = new Guid(callerID);
 .
 .
 .
 Entity Annotation = new Entity("annotation");
 Annotation.Attributes["objectid"] = new EntityReference("RelatedEntityLogical", RelatedEntity.Id);
 Annotation.Attributes["objecttypecode"] = RelatedEntity.LogicalName;
 .
 .
 .
 Annotation.Attributes["createdby"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", callerID);
 
 OrganizationServices.Create(Annotation);
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you receive right guid from the query string?

Comment: Yes, actually i am logging the guid, and it's correct in the query string

Comment: Sounds like a threading issue with racing condition. Does that sound a bell?

Comment: I applied Aron solution and still monitoring it, as its happen randomly, till now there is no issue

Comment: Hi, The issue still appears after applying Aron solution, what do you mean by threading issue?

Comment: You don't need to set created by attribute. THat field calculated automatically. It will depend on your OrganizationServices and ConnectionString

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

Do not set the `createdby` attribute - i.e. remove this line:
`Annotation.Attributes["createdby"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", callerID);`

Set the [CallerId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.callerid?view=dynamics-xrmtooling-ce-9) directly on the instance of CrmServiceClient:
`connection.CallerId = new Guid(callerID);`

Invoke `Create` directly from the instance of CrmServiceClient:
`connection.Create(Annotation);`

Comment: I will apply this change and let you know if fixed

Comment: Hi, the issue still appears after using connection (CrmServiceClient instance) to create the annotation entity

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the update. In looking again at your code, I see that you're parsing the `CallerId` out of the HTTP Request. That's a new one for me. When is this application running? What triggers it?

Comment: Its a web application deployed on iis and it's used in Dynamics CRM as IFRAME in the entity form, so the url of this iframe contains the entity id, and the user id, so we get the caller id (user id) from the query string, and we already log the caller id from the query string and it's correct.